# In the MongoDB java driver, will methods produce an error if the optional `ClientSession` is null?

Tags: java, mongodb

I've been creating an abstraction of the MongoDB java driver. Given the following block of code...

```
MongoCollection<Document> col = db.getCollection("something");
col.insertOne(session, someDocument);
```

Where session can be either `null` or an actual instance of `ClientSession`. Will I run into issues with this paradigm? I have many methods like this, including `col.replaceOne()`, `col.deleteOne`, `col.countDocuments()`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MongoDB Repository](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/379ba758274bf69b40eaf4002f7678321adec755/driver-sync/src/main/com/mongodb/client/internal/MongoCollectionImpl.java#L460), passing in a null `ClientSession` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.